# Verify $y = x\tan{x}$ is solution to ODE : $xy'=y+x^2+y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Verify
$$y = x\tan{x}$$
is a solution to
$$xy'=y+x^2+y^2$$

Comment: +1: In light of your self answer, I regard your question as high quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $y = x\tan(x).$ 
> Verify that $\displaystyle xy' = y + x^2 + y^2.$

Alternate approach:

$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}\tan(x) = \sec^2(x).$

$\tan^2(x) + 1 = \sec^2(x).$

---

LHS equals:

$$x \left[x\sec^2(x) + \tan(x)\right] = x^2[\tan^2(x) + 1] + y$$

$$ = x^2\tan^2(x) + x^2 + y = y^2 + x^2 + y.$$

Answer (score 0):

I just got the answer while asking this:

$$\begin{align}y'&=\tan{x}+x\frac{1}{\cos^2{x}}\\y'&=\tan{x}+x\frac{\cos^2{x}+\sin^2{x}}{\cos^2{x}}\\y'&=\tan{x}+x+x\tan^2{x}\\y'&=y/x+x+y^2/x\\xy'&=y+x^2+y^2\end{align}$$

Comment: +1 : Completely valid approach.